# What are the rules for evaluating an indefinite integral by by expanding the integrand in power series and integrating the power series term by term.

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I was browsing through Carr's Synopsis, the book made famous by Srinivasa Ramanujan (available in archive.org), in page 319 . I found this: [image]

We usually integrate only definite integrals term by term, subject to some conditions. Are there conditions for indefinite integrals also? This is a problem in differential algebras, not calculus, I suppose.

Comment: You should be inside the radius of convergence of the power series.  Of course the indefinite integral formula means exactly that the derivative of the series on the right is the integrand.  All modern calculus texts should discuss this.

Comment: Would you please, for some of us, snopsise the snopsis referred to?

Comment: @ A rural Reader Hi! Sorry for the typo. It is actually Synopsis. This refers to the book `Elementary Results in Pure Mathematics containing Propositions, Formulae and Methods of analysis with abridged demonstrations' by G. S. Carr, commonly called Carr's Synopsis.  The self taught Indian Mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan learnt most of Mathematics from this book.

Comment: The power series resulting from the integration will always converge in the same region the original power series did, and to a function whose derivative will be the original power series. However, if the power series involves terms with negative exponent as in the example, that region will not include $0$, but will be symmetric about $0$ (remember that $\int \frac{dx}x = \log|x| + C$, not just $\log x + C$). Further, the "$C$" in the two regions of convergence can have different values. But the FTC only applies over a single connected region.